# ffmpeg single quote in drawtext

Tags: ffmpeg, escaping, drawtext

I haven't been able to get ffmpeg's drawtext video filter to draw apostrophes/single quotes when they are in drawtext's "text=" parameter, even when I escape them. Double quotes work fine, and apostrophes in text loaded from a file (e.g. textfile="example.txt") work fine. Is this a bug?

e.g.

```
ffmpeg -i test.mpg -vf drawtext="apostrophes don't print" ...
ffmpeg -i test.mpg -vf drawtext="even when they\'re escaped" ...
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Special character escapes are like violence: if they're not solving your problem, you're not using enough.

```
ffmpeg -i test.mpg -vf drawtext=text="It\\\\\'s so easy"
```

Produces a textual overlay that includes an apostrophe.  The text is being parsed a couple times, so you not only have to escape the quote, you also have to escape the slash escaping the quote.  Twice.

Your alternative of using a textfile *might* be a better method in this situation.

Comment: While composing this command line from Java I actually had to code: `this.watermarkText = watermarkText.replaceAll(":", "").replaceAll("\'", "\\\\\\\\\\\\'");` which, if you ask me, it totally whack.

Comment: lol, I had the issue that I used single quotes also where this example uses double quotes around the text value. That doesn't work apparently, it needs to be double quotes. Or in my case I use a more complex -vf where I put the whole argument of -vf in double quotes and then don't use any quotes for the drawtext text value. Hope this may help someone. Thanks

Comment: I had to use more violence for it to work 
ffmpeg -i test.mpg -vf drawtext=text="It\\\\\\\'s so easy"

Answer (score 13):

I was able to insert Unicode **\u2019** into argument string and it worked for single right quote.

Comment: how did you insert that? If i have a variable $string containing the text with the quote, what should I do to get the quote printed?

Comment: Filix this is the only way I could make it work using the node tool fluent-ffmpeg. Thanks! :) 
`string.replace(/'/g, "\u2019"); // then feed this to the text property of drawtext`

Comment: This also worked for me in JavaScript: ```text = text.replace(/'/g, `\\\\\'`); text = text.replace(/\'/g, "\\" + `\\\\\'`);```.

Comment: THIS IS SO HELPFUL

Answer (score 5):

In case someone needs this for Python, this escape function is working for me (based on [the FFmpeg Quoting and Escaping documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Quoting-and-escaping) + multi-escaping advice above):

```py
return "'" + text.replace(":", "\\\\:").replace("'", "'\\\\\\\\\\\\''") + "'"
```

Comment: Not sure how this would be working for you it produces `it's` -> `'it'\\\''s'`

Comment: `return text.replace(":", "\\:").replace("'", "\\\\\\\\\\\\'")`

Comment: It could depend on shell, I am using zsh :)

Comment: what would that command be for bash, if I have my string with quote in $string? I'm completely confused as to how many \ I should add, is it 5, is it 12?

Comment: You sir, are a lifesaver!

Answer (score 5):

// This works for me

```
public function replaceSpecialFfmpegChars($text)
    {
        return str_replace(
            ":",
            "\\\\\\\\\\\:",
            str_replace(
                "%",
                "\\\\\\\\\\\%",
                str_replace(
                    "'",
                    "'\\\\\\\\\\\\''",
                    str_replace(
                        "\"",
                        "\\\\\\\\\\\"",
                        str_replace(
                            "\\",
                            "\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",
                            $text
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        );
    }
```

Comment: Ok, cool and working, thanks!!... but seriously... 

Answer (score 1):

Just put your text into a file e.g. myText.txt and use `textfile` option:

`->myText.txt`
This is my text with special characters :,(,),'

Then instead of using :

`ffmpeg -i test.mpg -vf drawtext="This is my text with special characters :,(,),'"`

use the following command:

`ffmpeg -i test.mpg -vf textfile=textFile.txt`

Comment: I am using a bat file with draw text inside a filter_complex, and only this method worked for me, all other method using escape string didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

This is probably something to do with magic quotes.  Through a bunch of testing I just did using Windows Command Line and MinGW on Windows,  I ran into the same problem every time.  Since ffmpeg drawtext uses Freetype (I would guess this is where magic quotes are enabled) I doubt there's much to be done to disable magic quotes.  I'm not sure there's a way to remove the added slashes in the command line either, as everything I've seen involves PHP scripts.  I could be wrong, since I'm no PHP guru, but I'm not aware of how to integrate them into an ffmpeg command.

Comment: Interesting, doesn't look like there's a solution then! Weird that it is possible to escape double quotes, semicolons etc. but not single quotes though...

Comment: Yeah apostrophes are always the big problem.  Whoever came up with magic quotes apparently decided that whenever you used it, it was always going to be an apostrophe in a contraction or to show ownership, where it's curved toward the preceding letter.  I never did like magic quotes.

Answer (score 0):

If you're passing the string via `Python`, the following works for me:

```
txt = 'it\'s good!'
txt = txt.replace('\'', '\'\\\\\\\\\\\'\'')
```

Answer (score 0):

in node.js, i am able to put a colon in the text with this line.

```
let surahTxt = "QURAN " + chapterNo + "\\:"+ from + "-" + to ;
```

later this variable is used with the drawtext

Answer (score 0):

**For Windows Users:**

The logic: for easier understanding I will call the single quote to be shown as a result: apostrophe and all other single quotes simply single quotes...

You have to put the first part of the text before the apostrophe between single quotes + 3 backslashes before the apostrophe, then the apostrophe itself + the text after the apostrophe between single quotes again"

So to produce: "apostrophes don't print" it would be:

**`drawtext=text='apostrophes don'\\\''t print'`**

Using an example:

```
ffplay -f lavfi  "color=blue:size=700x200,drawtext=text='apostrophes don'\\\''t print':fontsize=40:fontcolor=white:x=(W-tw)/2:y=(H-th)/2"
```

[image]

The other solution seems to be, to use a text file as already mentioned here by others:

drawtext=textfile=somefile.txt

Answer (score 0):

[ricardo-bohner](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74390947/revisions)'s methods works really well, ***but just make sure that,*** you're getting exactly the as shown below:

> **I used this;**

```
line = it's
str(line.replace("'", "'\\\\\\''"))
```

> **but due to the way I code some functions** in the executed command, I got **`'\\\''`** like below:

```
it'\\\''s
```