# bash: replace single quote with multiple backslashes in variable

Tags: bash

I have a variable containing a string with a quote:

```
echo $variable
It's my variable
```

to be able to use this variable as a legend for ffmpeg, I need to add 5 backslashes before the quote:

```
variable="It\\\\\'s my variable"
```

I'm confused as to what syntax I should use, as the backslashes and quotes have very specific meanings in bash replace commands. I have tried this:

```
variable=`echo $variable | tr "'" "\\\\\'"`
```

but it does not produce the correct result

Comment: Are you sure you need five backslashes? I think that maybe you just need to quote the variable when you use it in your `ffmpeg` command

Comment: @TomFenech I take that from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10725225/ffmpeg-single-quote-in-drawtext/10729560

Comment: You shouldn't ever have an odd number of backslashes.

Comment: Per Tom's comment, I'd be very interested to see what it is you're doing that requires five backslashes. Can you please include how you're using `$variable` in your question? This sounds very much like an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). Let's fix the underlying issue, rather than help you figure out how to do this the wrong way. :-)

Comment: You could use an ansi c string. `$'It\'s my variable'`

Comment: @ghoti it all comes from this answer I'm linking to, in which there are five backslashes: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10729560/1967110

Comment: It's likely that the number of escapes that you will need will be different because that answer described a manual command line invocation and you're using variable expansion. Be prepared to do some testing.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use some single quotes yourself to tell bash not to interpret those slashes:

```
variable="It"'\\\\\'"'s my variable"
```

Edit: To convert an existing variable use:

```
variable=${variable//\'/'\\\\\'\'}
```

Comment: the problem is that my variable gets its content from a file, I am not defining it myself. so I really need a way to escape the quote after the variable has been created

Answer (score 0):

This works fine, is portable and does not have the problems of sed:

```
echo "$v" |perl -pe "s/'/\x5c\x5c\x5c\x5c\x5c'/g"
```

PS: `\x5c` is the ascii code of slash `\`