# ffmpeg: use drawtext with quote inside text

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a variable that takes its content from a file (I can't change the content of the file):

```
echo $variable
It's my variable
```

I want to print that string on a video with ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -nostdin -i input.mp4 -vf drawtext="text='$variable': fontcolor=white:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.8: x=h/70: y=h/5*4.2" -codec:a copy output.mp4
```

when I do that, the quote inside $variable is not printed. I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10725225/ffmpeg-single-quote-in-drawtext) that I need to escape the quote multiple times, some say 5 times, some say more.

So I have tried to use

```
variable=${variable//\'/'\\\\\'\'}
```

to add between 1 and 10 backslashes, but it never worked: either nothing is printed, or \ are printed:

```
It\s my variable
```

Can someone tell me what is the correct syntax, or the correct number of backslashes I should add?

Comment: In bash on Windows inside mintty, this works: `text=$variable`. No quotes around the variable reference. With quotes. the reference gets echoed.

Comment: @Mulvya not working for me in a bash script on Ubuntu

Comment: Check directly in the shell.

Answer (score 0):

On linux I do

```
$variable = str_replace("'", "\\\\\\\\\\'", $variable);
```

On Windows

```
$variable = str_replace("'", "\\\\\\'", $variable);
```